# Is there any way to take a picture with the raspbery cam and store it on a matrix

Tags: raspicam

I want to do something like this

```
import cv2
from time import sleep
import numpy as np

# Set up the camera such that it closes
# when we are done with it

print("about take a picture")

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:

    camera.resolution = (3280,2464)
    mat1=camera.capture()
    cv2.imshow("picture",mat1)
```

But there is a problem I dont know how to storage the RPI cam on a variable, or how to make only a read of the cam without saying that is mandatory to storage an image

Comment: You could check the Picamera documentation and search for `array`. https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=array&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`picamera.capture()` can be used to capture the image to a stream-like object (an io.BytesIO stream) or even directly to a numpy array.

An example from [here](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#capturing-to-a-numpy-array) shows how to do it and gives important notes to the resolution (rounding up the requested resolution). It is necessary to keep this rounding in mind when allocating a buffer object as it must be large enough to receive all the image data. So fetching the data might require are larger buffer and the uninitialized pixels have to be stripped off afterwards (there's an example in the documenation linked above).

```
import time
import picamera
import numpy as np

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (320, 240)
    camera.framerate = 24
    time.sleep(2)
    output = np.empty((240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    camera.capture(output, 'rgb')
```

> It is also important to note that when outputting to unencoded formats, the camera rounds the requested resolution. The horizontal resolution is rounded up to the nearest multiple of 32 pixels, while the vertical resolution is rounded up to the nearest multiple of 16 pixels.